# Test method setter @Input() Angular 4 Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-runner

How can I test this method from the component:

```
@Input() set camera(camera: CameraModel) {
    this._camera = camera;
    if (this._camera && this._camera.cameraId) {
        this.fetchVideos(this._camera);
    }
}
```

In the test, you need to give him my stub, but as I have not tried, it does not work...

**Info**

If I use setter as a method in the test, I get the error "component.camera is not a function"

```
TypeError: component.camera is not a function
at Object.eval (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/src/app/components/dashboard-videos-list/dashboard-videos-list.component.spec.ts?:86:23)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:392:26)
at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js?:49:39)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js?:76:39)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:391:32)
at Zone.runGuarded (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:155:47)
at runInTestZone (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js?:128:25)
at Object.eval (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js?:67:13)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:392:26)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///D:/dev/nighthawk/frontend/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js?:79:39)
```

Test before each:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardVideosListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Test:

```
describe('set camera', () => {
    it('success', async(() => {
        component.camera(new CameraModel({
            cameraId: 13
        }));

        expect(component._camera['cameraId']).toBe(13);
    }));
});
```

Comment: You need to provide more info. What doesn't work, what errors do you see? How do you set the input property in your test? How do you test for it being set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of

```
   component.camera(new CameraModel({
       cameraId: 13
   }));
```

you want

```
component.camera = new CameraModel({});
```

Since it is an input setter you aren't really calling the function more that the function runs everytime you give it a new value. (:

Comment: Its not working for me